# Run all tests in spock

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I want to run all spock specs in the given directory sharing the same driver instance. Also I want to keep running all the test even if some tests fail and generate a html report. With cucumber it was easy to do by just running cucumber in the given directory.
How to do it with spock. I am using geb with spock for grails application's functional testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `build.gradle` file contains something like this:

```
task test(overwrite: true, dependsOn: drivers.collect { tasks["${it}Test"] })
```

then, to run the tests use the following commands:

```
gradlew chromeTest
gradlew firefoxTest
```

To run the tests for all the browsers, you can run the following command:

```
gradlew test
```

This should continue running even one of the test fails and when it will finish, gradle will provide you the location for the html report.